# Characters merge in a weird way in text editors like Notepad

Tags: fonts, text-editors, text-editing

I downloaded the font `Space Mono` (regular) from Google Fonts ([link](https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Space+Mono&query=Space+Mono)), and also the font `Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01` from its website ([link](http://www.fixedsysexcelsior.com/)).

In text editors like Visual Studio Code and Brackets, these fonts display fine. (Visual Studio Code and Brackets are text editors for web development, and they are developed with the help of node.js)

However, when I use these fonts in Notepad, Visual Studio Code, or a `<textarea>` in a webpage (displayed in Google Chrome, `63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)`), characters start showing weird behaviour and start to merge with each other when I type a sequence of characters.

#### Here's an example (Notepad)

The text that you see in each image is the same, and is rendered correctly in the first image.

- Courier New (rendered correctly):

[image]

- Space Mono (rendered wrong):

[image]

- Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01 (rendered wrong):

[image]

I use a laptop running Windows 8. I also tested this on Windows 10 Pro (version 1709). Same problem.

My question is, why is this happening, and how can I avoid this? It's a bit of an annoyance to me.

Comment: Use a different font, or use notepad++ where it works.

Comment: I want to use the font without it rendering like that in every text editor. I kinda like the Space Mono font, except that it renders like that in Visual Studio, so it becomes ugly.